# How to add a new "comment" or "flag" field to every model field of existing model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Disclaimer: I can wipe out the database anytime. So while answering this, please don't care about migrations and stuff.

Imagine me having a model with multiple values:

```py
class Compound(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, default="")
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, default="")
    temperature = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    melting_temp = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    # more (~20) especially numeric values as model fields
```

Now I want to **add a comment** to be stored **for every value of that model**. For example I want to add a comment "measured in winter" to the `temperature` model field.

What is the best approach to do that?

My brainstorming came up with:

1. By hand add 20 more model fields like `temperature_comment = ...`  but that sounds not very DRY
2. Add one big json field which stores every comment. But how do I create a Form with such a json field? Because I want to separate each input field for related value. I would probably have to use javascript which I would want to avoid.
3. Add a model called `Value` for every value and connect them to `Compound` via `OneToOneField`s. But how do I then create a Form for `Compound`? Because I want to create a `Compound` utilizing one form. I do not want to create every `Value` on its own. Also it is not as easy as before, to access and play around with the values inside the `Compound` model.

I guess this is a fairly abstract question for a usecase that comes up quite often. I do not know why I did not find resources on how to accomplish that.

Comment: My model has 25 values of different types. Now every value needs a comment or info or description; basically a `model.CharField` with always the same lenght. Should I just add 25 more fields now, or is there a better way? temperature = 23, temperature_comment = "measured in may", color = "blue", color_comment = "painted by Anna" and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Pythonic way is to use a [metaclass](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses):

```py
class CommentModelMeta(models.base.ModelBase):
    def __new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs, **kwargs):
        for attr_name, attr in list(attrs.items()):
            if isinstance(attr, models.Field):
                attrs[f'{attr_name}_comment'] = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, default="")
        return super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs, **kwargs)


class Compound(models.Model, metaclass=CommentModelMeta):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, default="")
    ...
```

If you need code completion, you can use type hints:

```py
class Compound(models.Model, metaclass=CommentModelMeta):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, default="")
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, default="")
    temperature = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    melting_temp = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    # more (~20) especially numeric values as model fields

    color_comment: models.CharField
    temperature_comment: models.CharField
```

Comment: I don't think metaclasses are the best implementation for this. "Metaclasses are deeper magic that 99% of users should never worry about it. If you wonder whether you need them, you don't (the people who actually need them know with certainty that they need them, and don't need an explanation about why)." - Python Guru Tim Peters.

Comment: @vinkomlacic The "boring" way of explicitly defining fields is indeed clearer. I did not say it is the best implementation, and the asker certainly does not *need* it. Still, it is a very reasonable Pythonic way to achieve such abstraction.

Comment: To be honest: I think there is no 100% correct answer to this. I tried all answers though and this one is the solution which does not require a lot of code rewriting and serves the purpose. I finally refuse to use the metaclass, as I think it is too advanced and just added 20 more fields to the model "by hand". I would go for the metaclass in case of maybe 50 fields though.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're right by going with the 3rd approach. If every value needs to have a comment, than that value is kind of a complex field. The only issue is that it's going to make rendering kind of hard to do, but not too complex.

Also, I would go even further and use a one-to-many field between `Compound` and `Value`. One `Compound` has many values. Each of them has a name, value to be stored and a comment.

When dealing with a form for this, you can dynamically create a form in the `__init__` method.

The issue might be that you lose the intended validation in your form, but maybe you can think of how to improve this. You could create different subtypes of `Value`, e.g. `NumericValue` and so on.

```py
# models.py
class Compound(models.Model):

    def save(self, **kwargs)
        creating = self.pk is None
     
        super().save(**kwargs)

        if creating:
             # Initialize all values
             self.values.create(name='temperature')
             ...


class Value(models.Model):
    compound = models.ForeignKey(Compound, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='values')
    # field name e.g. melting_temp
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)  
    # verbose name e.g. Melting Temperature
    label = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True) 
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    note = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

```py
# forms.py
class CompoundForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Create a field for each value
        for value in self.instance.values.all():
            # In this field, you enter the value
            self.fields[value.name] = forms.CharField(label=value.label)

            # In this field, you enter the comment (note)
            self.fields[f'{value.name}_note'] = forms.CharField(label='Note')
    
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super().save(*args, **kwargs)
      
        # Save values
        # You can speed this up using Value.objects.bulk_update
        for value in instance.values.all():
            value.value = self.cleaned_data.get(value.name)
            value.note = self.cleaned_data.get(f'{value.name}_note')
            value.save()
```

Comment: Thank you! Only problem here would be, that some of my `Values` need an `IntegerField`, some a `FloatField`, some even a `CharField`. I therefore had to create ~20 models, inheriting from `Value` model. And at that point it got fairly messy. It was a nice learning-journey though.

Comment: Why ~20? Isn't three enough?

Comment: This one is a very good solution as well. If I face the same problem in my next project, I would go for this approach **from the beginning**. But as I am already deeply involved and don't want to do a lot of rewriting this is not doing it for me. Also I figured that manually adding 20 more fields is less time consuming (but 4 sure way more boring).

Answer (score 1):

I would go with a JSONfield.

It's quite easy to dynamically create a form with a Charfield matching every field in a model. The keys to this are (a) [the documented Model._meta interface](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/meta/) (don't be perturbed by that underscore) and (b) the three-argument form of the Python `type` built-in.

I'm writing this off the top of my head, but let's add a JsonField `comments` to our object(s) and then construct a form with a Charfield for every field in `Compound` except `comments`:

```
def construct_form_class( obj):
    # obj can be an instance or a ModelClass.   
    # we probably don't want a comment for the primary key or the comments field
    exclude = ( 'id', 'comments')

    form_fields = {}
    for field in Compound._meta.get_fields() :
        name = field.name
        if name in exclude:
            continue
        charfield = forms.Charfield(
            max_length = 120,
            # anything else? Maybe look up suitable initial based on field name?
            # otherwise blank=True or initial='something'
        )
        form_fields[ name] = charfield

    # construct the form class
    MyForm = type( 'MyForm', (forms.Form, ), form_fields )
    return MyForm
```

Now a view for updating the comments on a particular instance `compound`. The class includes SingleObjectMixin, which provides everything we need to fetch that instance via `get_object` and the usual declarations. ( [Classy CBVs](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.2/django.views.generic.edit/FormView/) comes in handy, as ever)

```
def UpdateCommentsView( SingleObjectMixin, FormView)

    template_name = 'app:update_comments.html'
    model = Compound
    ...

    def setup( self, request, *args, **kwargs):
         super().setup( request, *args, **kwargs)
         self.object = self.get_object()

    def get_form_class(self):
         return construct_form_class( self.object)  # above

    def get_initial(self)
         return self.object.comments.copy() 

    def form_valid( self, form):
         # form.cleaned_data that has passed validation is an
         # appropriate value {fieldname: value, ...} to store
         # in a JsonField.
         self.object.comments = form.cleaned_data
         self.object.save()
```

Think this is everything essential. No code change is needed if you add a field to the model with a subsequent migration. The dynamically generated form will automatically have a new field with the same name as the model field.

The template can be as simple as presenting `{{form.as_p}}` to the user.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating on my JSONfield approach! You very well covered my struggles with javascript as your approach does not need it. But finally the jsonfield brings a bit of overhead when it comes to extracting. Although working, it still feels like a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an *abstract base model*:

```
class CommentBase(models.Model):
    comment = models.CharField(
        max_length=128, blank=True, default=None, null=True
    )
    # …

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Then you can mix that model in your models:

```
class Compound(CommentBase, models.Model):
    # …
    pass


class Other(CommentBase, models.Model):
    # ..
    pass


# …
```

It will automatically add the field(s) defined in `CommentBase` to the models that inherit from `CommentBase`.

Comment: I guess this relates to my 3. approach, right? I would have to create an abstract class and then create 24 models, for every value that I want to add a comment to. Then I would have to sum them up in the `Compound` model, connecting them all via `OneToOneField`

Comment: @Tarquinius: no, since here this will not create an extra table, nor generate relations, etc.

Comment: Ok, first of: Thank you for helping me. But can you please add 2 example model fields to your answer to make it more clear to me? Go with `temperature` and `brand`. Right now I do not see any usecase for your presented model called `Other`. Also `Compound` now has only one field for comment, but I need a comment for every single of the 24 fields!

Answer (score 0):

One can also use django many-to-many field relationships to handle it, as specified in the documentation [Django many-to-many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/). Since in winter there can be many temperature measurements with different timestamps, and vice-versa

```
from django.db import models
class Compound(models.Model):
    color = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, default="")
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, default="")
    temperature = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    melting_temp = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    # more (~20) especially numeric values as model fields

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['temperature']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tempertaure

class Comment(models.Model):
    datetime = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    comment = models.ManyToManyField(Compound)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['datetime']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline
```

One can use the python datetime time stamps as strings to save it along with the comments for every melting_temp

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the access pattern of the model.

you could have a model1 for values, model2 for comments, one2one relation.

If you access one model more than the other you don't have to load and resolve text or varchar each time.